# Can I make the global application menu show the full application title?

Tags: 10.10, unity, appmenu

I've been using Ubuntu Netbook Edition as my main OS for a while now. I really like it, but I have one complaint. Whenever an application as a long title, it gets cut off. For example the terminal works fine. See:

[image]

And the ones that don't work:

[image: http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/9214/badc.png]

This should say **Text Editor** but instead it shows **Text** and a huge empty space. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: It is important to maintain the consistency of the location of the menu bar - notice the title area is fixed. The second word has been eliminated because it would not fit into the given area.

Comment: @Toki: Thats actually a really good point. Still they should allow me to override it if thats not what I want. Also mac's don't do this and no one seems to care too much.

Comment: How about you file bug report regarding customizing title area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed in Ubuntu 11.04 which will be released later in April. The full application title shows up except when you mouseover the title which reveals the File, Edit, View menu instead.